# Add a "loop mode" to my slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I got this simple horizontal slideshow (I've been working on it  for a while now) with left/right buttons to navigate it. It doesn't have a "continuous" play - returning to the begining or end when clicking the respective buttons. Here's the jQuery code:

```
var menuItem_place = 0;
var menuItem_position = 0;
var menuItem_limit = parseInt($('.menuItem').length) - 1;

$('.menuItem:first .content').css({margin: 0, height: '100%', lineHeight: '99px'})

// Rocks menu scroll LEFT button mouse events
$('#rocksMenu_btnLeft').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'-26px'}, 150);
});
$('#rocksMenu_btnLeft').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).stop(true).animate({'background-position-x':'-52px'}, 150);
});
$('#rocksMenu_btnLeft').on('click', function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'0px'}, 150,
    function(){
      $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'-26px'}, 150);
      // Slide items backward
      if (menuItem_place > 0){
       menuItem_place --;
      }
      menu_animateClick();
    }
  );
});

// Rocks menu scroll RIGHT button mouse events
$('#rocksMenu_btnRight').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'-26px'}, 150);
});
$('#rocksMenu_btnRight').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).stop(true).animate({'background-position-x':'0px'}, 150);
});
$('#rocksMenu_btnRight').on('click', function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'-52px'}, 150,
    function(){
      $(this).animate({'background-position-x':'-26px'}, 150);
      // Slide items forward
      if (menuItem_place < menuItem_limit){
        menuItem_place ++;
      }
      menu_animateClick();
    }
  );
});

function menu_animateClick() {
    menuItem_position = 0 - (menuItem_place * 200);
    $('#menuContainer').stop().animate({left: menuItem_position + 'px'}, 300);
}
```

I'd like to add that feature to my code - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/64tu2/)

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64tu2/4/

Comment: So if I really get what you want. I added an else statement to each incremetation and decrementation of menuItem_place.

Comment: Perfect. @Maroua Gasmi, please post an answer so I can give you the green checkmark. :D Thanx!

Comment: I would need a green checkmark :) happy that my answer helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an else statement to each incremetation and decrementation of menuItem_place.

```
if(menuItem_place > 0)
       menuItem_place --;
        else
      menuItem_place  =3;
```

and

```
  if (menuItem_place < menuItem_limit){
    menuItem_place ++;
  }
    else
     menuItem_place = 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64tu2/4/